# Unable to Load Images to Carousel

Tags: firebase, flutter, carousel

I am trying to load multiple images to the `Carousel`. The images I am obtaining are from `Firebase` Realtime Database.

This is my main.dart :

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var databaseRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    final List<String> imgList = [];
    databaseRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Sliders");
    databaseRef2.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;

      values.forEach((key, values) {
        imgList.add(values["img"]);
        print('List IS ${imgList}');
      });
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My App"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 385.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInBack,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 900),
              viewportFraction: 0.8,
            ),
            items: imgList.map((e) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 250,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        blurRadius: 3,
                        spreadRadius: 3,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    e,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          ),
        ],
  }
}
```

I am getting the Images successfully and adding all the images to a list :

```
List IS [https://c.ndtvimg.com/2020-05/9iuj3h1g_indian-food_625x300_19_May_20.jpg, https://www.thecoldwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/selection-of-indian-food.jpg]
```

But, the images are not showing in the Carousel.

There is no error in the Debug console as well.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: if you have any `Future` data you should use `FutureBuilder`, so you need to initialize your `Future` inside `initState` for example and use that `Future` in `FutureBuilder` inside `build` method, more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Did you forget to call `setState`?

Comment: Where to add setState ? @AnteBule

Comment: @pskink Where to use FutureBuilder ?

Comment: all you need is `FutureBuilder` -  more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Below or around `values.Foreach`, like `setState(() { values.forEach((key, values) {
        imgList.add(values["img"]);
        print('List IS ${imgList}');
      }); });`. Or like `values.forEach((key, values) {
        imgList.add(values["img"]);
        print('List IS ${imgList}');
      }); setState((){});` @Zibran

Comment: @pskink I also agree, that's probably even better.

Comment: @AnteBule yes indeed, `FutureBuilder` is designed for cases like that (btw it uses `setState` internally but the end user should not know about it)

Comment: @AnteBule I added setState() , still the image aren't loading. Pls help

Comment: You should move fetching logic outside of `build` method, because when you call `setState` it fires all over again.